# SSH viewer like behaviour

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, eye-strain

Is it possible to SSH into a shared shell session? I suffer from eye strain/computer vision syndrome and want to use my (jailbreaked) eink Kindle to SSH into a computer but use that host machines keybord for input. So if I type on the hosts keyboard I want the input to appear in the SSH session on my Kindle.

I got the terminal and SSH client working on the Kindle so I only need some solution for the serverside. VNC is a bit messy on todays b/w eink screens so SSH will do.

Any help deeply appreciated as it would allow me to stay in business!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a multi-user screen session. The screen utility can be used to view/use a single session with multiple users:

1. Start a new screen session with a specific name: `screen -S sessionname`
2. Open the session on another terminal with `screen -x sessionname`

You can also do this with different users on the same machine. To do this:

1. Make screen setuid using `chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen`
2. Run screen with `screen -s sessionname`
3. Enable multiuser mode with ctrl+a `:multiuser on`
4. Allow a different user to connect with ctrl+a `:addacl guestuser`
5. As the guest user, use `screen -x hostingUserName/sessionname`

Comment: I thought of screen just after posting. Thanks for the thorough instructions. Will try out and come back for answer-rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a connection to a server in shared mode. a shell session is running on a machine on a device "tty" or "pty". in that case you use tmux or screen

Comment: From your post it is not clear at all how to achieve what you describe. Could you please describe in more details?